# In Scala, given a list of lists, how can I create one nested HashMap from the elements?

Tags: scala, hashmap

In Scala, given a list of lists, how can I create one nested HashMap from the elements? I would like to create the HashMap as a hierarchical tree such that for an element at index i, the element at index i - 1 is its parent.

Example for lists of known length:

```
val lst = List (
  List(34, 56, 78),
  List(34, 56,79),
  List (87, 23, 12),
  List(87, 90, 78),
  List(1, 45, 87)
)

scala> lst.groupBy(l => l(0))
  .mapValues(l => l.groupBy(x => x(1)))
  .mapValues{ case x => x.mapValues(y => y.map (z => z(2))) }
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[Int]]] = Map(34 -> Map(56 -> List(78, 79)), 1 -> Map(45 -> List(87)), 87 -> Map(23 -> List(12), 90 -> List(78)))
```

This method works when the length of the elements are known but does not work for an arbitrary length N. Is there any solution that can create this nested map for lists of any length where every list has the same length?

Comment: Why do you have Java as one of your tags?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just create a multi-tree data structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some preliminary tests seem to indicate that this might work.

```
def nest(lli: List[List[Int]]): Traversable[_] =
  if (lli.head.size == 1)
    lli.flatten.distinct
  else
    lli.groupBy(_.head)
       .mapValues(vs => nest(vs.map(_.tail)))
```

Comment: Wow this is beautiful, any edge cases that you can think of?

Comment: You probably won't get the right result if not all the sub-lists are the same size but, so far, I haven't seen it throw any errors.

Comment: All my sublists all the same size. I tested it on a few of my data sets and lgtm. Thanks again!

Comment: After looking it over I've come up with a slight modification.  Same thing (I think), just a little more concise.

Answer (score 0):

```
private def buildPartitionTree(partitionValues: List[List[Any]]): Map[Any, Any] = {
    val valuesAsNestedMaps = partitionValues.map(_.foldRight(Map[Any,Map[Any,_]]()) { case (partitionValue, map) =>
      Map(partitionValue.toString -> map)
    }).map(_.asInstanceOf[Map[Any, Any]])

    valuesAsNestedMaps.reduce[Map[Any, Any]] { case (map1: Map[Any, Any], map2: Map[Any, Any]) => mergeMaps(map1, map2) }
  }

private def mergeMaps(map1 : Map[Any, Any], map2 : Map[Any, Any]) = (map1.keySet ++ map2.keySet).map(key =>
    key -> mergeMapValues(map1.get(key), map2.get(key))
  ).toMap

private def mergeMapValues(o1 : Option[Any], o2 : Option[Any]): Any = (o1, o2) match {
    case (Some(v1: Map[Any, Any]), Some(v2: Map[Any, Any])) => mergeMaps(v1, v2)
    case (None, Some(x)) => x
    case (Some(y), None) => y
  }
val nestedMap = buildPartitionTree(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the size of sublists is arbitrary you cannot specify the result type of desired function. Consider introducing recursive data structure like this:

```
trait Tree[A]
case class Node[A](key:A, list:List[Tree[A]]) extends Tree[A]
case class Leaf[A](value:A) extends Tree[A]
```

Now you can create function producing desired result in terms of trees:

```
def toTree[A](key:A, list:List[List[A]]):Tree[A] = 
  if (list.exists(_.isEmpty)) Leaf(key)
  else Node(key, list.groupBy(_.head).map {case (k,v) => toTree(k, v.map(_.tail))}.toList)
```

Since you don't have 'root' value for key, you can call toTree function with some fake key:

```
toTree(-1, lst)
res1: Node(-1,List(Node(34,List(Node(56,List(Leaf(79), Leaf(78))))), Node(1,List(Node(45,List(Leaf(87))))), Node(87,List(Node(23,List(Leaf(12))), Node(90,List(Leaf(78)))))))
```

Comment: This works but I specifically need a hashmap for my serialization requirements.